Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int?" and 'IQueryable<int?>
void load3(long id_pro)
{

    var data3 = from p in db.Product_details
            join c in db.LoaiSps
            on p.id_loai equals c.id_Loai
            where p.id_loai == (from d in db.Product_details
                                where d.id_product_detail == id_pro
                                select d.id_loai)
            select p;

    if (data3 != null && data3.Count() > 0)
    {
        product3 = data3.ToList();
    }
}

I tried looking at a post from someone who had the same problem as me, adding First() or Single() but it still doesn't seem to work.

doesnt it make more sense to add the second where directly into the query?
So to write where p.id_product_detail == id_pro instead of the whole where p.id_loai == ...

Even as SQL this query would fail if no results or more than 1 result were returned. I'm surprised it compiles at all. What is this code trying to query? EF (and any other ORM) have no need for JOINs, it's their job to generate JOINS from relations. ORMs let you work with application objects instead of tables, they're not meant to let you write Embedded SQL

In any case the error is clear - you can't compare a single value with a query that can return 1, 1000 or no results at all. A correct LINQ query would be eg db.Produtcs.Include(p=>p.Details).ThenInclude(d=>d.Loads).ToList()

The expression if (data3 != null && data3.Count() > 0) is bad as well. data3 is a query, not data, and can never be null. data3.Count() executes that query. That executes the data3 query twice when just data3.ToList() would have the same result.

avoid the sub select
var data3 = from p in db.Product_details
            join c in db.LoaiSps
            on p.id_loai equals c.id_Loai
            where db.Product_details ==  id_pro 
            select p   
             
if (data3.Any())
{
    product3 = data3.ToList();
}


This appears to be the correct query to me:
void load3(long id_pro)
{
    var data3 =
    (
        from p in db.Product_details
        where p.id_product_detail == id_pro
        join c in db.LoaiSps on p.id_loai equals c.id_Loai
        select p
    ).ToArray();

    if (data3.Any())
    {
        product3 = data3.ToList();
    }
}

I'd also argue that the .Any() is unneeded as it's likely that you want to update product3 if the data is empty.
